# React calling function using useEffect multiple time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I tried to calling a function more then 2 times using useEffect hook but the result it only calling that function with last call.

here is my code and try :

```
 const [ selectValues, setSelectValues ] = useState([]);
 const selectHandler = (e) => {
 const filteredValues = selectValues.filter((i) => i.id !== e.id);
     setSelectValues([ ...filteredValues, e ]);
  }; 

useEffect(() => {
  const obj1 = {...}
  const obj2 = {...}
  selectHandler(obj1)
  selectHandler(obj2) // this is the only object will be saved to the state
},[])
```

I hope that issue explained properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to save any intermediate values from the state, you should update it in a callback manner, because `selectValues` contains the value which was there when component was rendered (initial value in our case).

```js
const selectHandler = (e) => {
  setSelectValues((prevValues) => [...prevValues.filter((i) => i.id !== e.id), e]);
};
```